# Efficient way to find if an integer is one of sums of integers

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

This is a school assignment, however, the requirement was that the program be "implemented with maximum performance" - which is vague to my taste, because I don't know would memory outweigh speed or not etc. But what I'm looking for is whether there is a "tricky" way to solve the problem by doing some smart manipulation on the input data.

So, here's the problem: consider you have two arrays, A and B, write a function that returns 1 if there is such integer in B, that equals to the sum of any two *subsequent* elements of A.

Below is my writeup. Note that I didn't use `Hashmap<Integer>` because I considered the memory required for the speedup to be a disadvantage strong enough to live with the O(n * m) speed as my worst case instead of O(n).

```
public static int arrayContainsSum(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int offsetA = a.length - 1;
    int offsetB = offsetA;
    int index = b.length - 1;
    int result = 0;
    int tested;

    while (index >= 0)
    {
        if (offsetA > 0) a[offsetA] += a[--offsetA];
        else if (offsetA == 0) // This has a danger of overflowing the int
            a[offsetA--] = multiply(a);
        tested = b[index];
        if ((offsetA < 0 && tested != 0 && a[0] % tested != 0) ||
            offsetB == 0)
        {
            // No point to test this element as it doesn't 
            //divide the product of sums
            offsetB = a.length - 1;
            index--;
        }
        if (tested == a[offsetB--])
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static int multiply(int[] input)
{
    int accumulator = input.length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    for (int i : input)
        if (i != 0) accumulator *= i;
    return accumulator;
}
```

There are some things I'm not concerned with: integer overflow (which might happen as a result of multiplication). I assumed `array.length` to be as fast as reading from local variable.

But, again, my question is rather "wasn't it possible to solve this problem analytically?" which would mean better efficiency?

PS. The problem doesn't mention if arrays contain only unique members - no limitations on that. I also think it would be possible to optimize (if I detect such case) by sorting `a` so that in case that the `b[x]` is smaller than the smallest element in `a` or greater then the largest element in `a`, it would save some lookups - but, again, this would come on expense of increased complexity, possibly, not entirely justified.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question means; what do you mean by "analytically" in this case?

Comment: If you want to do this with O(1) memory, yes sorting the array and then doing binary search would be better (a and b are the sizes of the arrays): O(a*b) vs. O(a log a + b * log a). If a == b, then it's O(a^2) vs. O(a log a). The optimal algorithm speedwise (as you already know) has O(a) extra memory, but runs in O(b) time.

Comment: I must say that I don't understand why you need to invoke a multiply (I haven't figured out what your code is doing, but this stood out for me...)

Comment: @Oli I don't understand the algorithm at all, I'd write this as a simple for loop and a `contains` call. I just went by the problem description above it (which has a bug as well, since we only reference array b there..)

Comment: @wvxvw: Hmm, that still doesn't make a lot of sense.  I imagine I'd have to unpick your code to figure out why that's relevant...

Comment: In most cases you won't be achieving much with the product-of-sums check, there are too many false positives (it doesn't eliminate many wrong attempts). Sorting the array in place (`Arrays.sort`) and binary search would pay off, I'd say.

Comment: @wvxvw You should always benchmark and not guess at performance. Whatever your current algorithm is doing it's way worse than the naive implementation according to my quick caliper test..

Comment: Going with a `HashSet` would make the code both trivial and fast, and would cause memory problems only with quite huge input sizes. A million members is still not much.

Comment: You said there was an array `A` but you don't say what is way for.

Comment: `you have two arrays, A and B, write a function that returns 1 if there is such integer in B, that equals to the sum of any two subsequent elements of B.` - maybe `elements of A` was meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int arrayContainsSum(int[] a, int[] b) {
  final Set<Integer> sums = new HashSet<Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) sums.add(a[i] + a[i+1]);
  for (int x : b) if (sums.contains(x)) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the two arrays are of very disparate lengths, and it is not known in advance which will be the longer one, then it would pay to first check which is longer and put that one in the HashSet and scan the other one in a loop.

Comment: Actually it doesn't make any difference. The solution is `O(a+b)` while the other is.. exactly the same. Even for practical purposes the difference between `add` and `contains` should be negligible. The only advantage is that we change the space reqs from `O(a)` to `O(min(a,b,))`.

Comment: Yes, thought about it in the meantime, reached the same conclusion. If either `add` or `contains` dominated the other, then it would have made sense to choose either the shorter or the longer one to put in the hashtable, but they are similar. Another idea I got is to use a `BitSet` in case the range of integers used is known to be relatively small.

Comment: I know this misses the point a bit, but doesn't this code miss half the `sums` cases, since it increments twice in each iteration? For instance, it will add `a[0] + a[1]` on the first iteration and `a[2] + a[3]` on the next, but never `a[1] + a[2]`. Wouldn't `a[i++] + a[i]` work better? Obviously a good answer, just nitpicking as I came across it.

Answer (score 0):

The speed does not matter unless you have over 1 million elements and it takes over 1 second. Btw, you do not want to make arrays of size over 1 million elements.

It's not fortunate that Java versions up to 7 do not contain even basic set operations. You can however find them in [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (that code is properly tested and as efficient as it can be).

Lets say you have 2 sets 20 elements, `a` and `b` - that are chosen by random from 1 to 100 and 200.

```
a = RandomInteger[{100}, 20]
b = RandomInteger[{200}, 20]
```

After that you want to find what elements of set of `a` sums of subsequent elements intersects with `b`

```
ap = Table[Total[{a[[i]], a[[i + 1]]}], {i, 1, Length[a] - 1}]
Intersection[ap, b]
```

For example:

```
{73,43,99,33,80,35,54,82,50,23,92,22,54,4,14,14,8,80,92,85}
{121,139,158,158,51,176,65,84,76,172,73,148,71,128,55,134,4,32,183,134}
{116,142,132,113,115,89,136,132,73,115,114,76,58,18,28,22,88,172,177}
{73,76,172}
```

Comment: Intersection is overkill. OP only needs existence.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken then by worst case, he needs to find if `Length[Intersection[ap,b]]` is 0. Therefor, how is that overkill?

Comment: If you can prove that length is 0 without calculating the intersection, then you are not calculating the intersection. I said that calculating the intersection is overkill.

Comment: Much more? Your thinking about better best case ... With Guava you can do this `return Sets.intersection(b, ap).size()==0;`, but I guess reinvesting the wheel gives more experience.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use brute force.

Well - of course, if the task is to write a performant solution, that might not be enough, but before you optimize a solution, you need a solution.

```
val a = List (3, 9, 7, 4, 16)    
val b = List (29, 12, 21, 16, 18, 14) 

for (i <- (0 to a.length - 2); 
  j = i+1;
  if b.exists (_ == a(i)+a(j))) yield (a(i), a(j), a(i)+a(j))
```

How often does it run? 
The outer loop runs from 1 to array-length-1 (which is a list here) to produce i, j is just the subsequent element.

But for b it runs always through the whole Array,

If you sort b by value, you could do a binary lookup in b. 
I guess a HashMap is not allowed from the rules, since you're given two Arrays. Else a HashMap is faster.

Comment: This would probably be the best balance between time and space, but wouldn't necessarily outperform a solution with a hashtable, which doesn't require any sorting.

Comment: @wvxvw: I made a silly mistake in my first posting. The elements shall be subsequently in one array, so we can't sort them. If the hashmap is allowed, it will be the fastest. But a sorted array can fast be binary searched.